# Handle Separator in data,Informatica Power exchange

Tags: informatica

Please assist how to handle a separator appears in string in Informatica Power exchange,Is there any function to replace or other ways.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate at bit more? What separator, how do you want to handle it, what have you tried so far, what it has got to do with PowerExchange, some examples with your expected output etc.

Comment: Was trying to read a comma separated csv file on mainframe  and separator also present in data string for few fields.Tried using field separator and delimiter options and could not solve instead data is moving to the next field.And one more option is not selecting field separator and extending all the fields length by 1 to read comma and  trimmed using function at power exchange.Any alternative for this?

Comment: Can you show how the data is coming. If comma separated file has comma inside a field and the field is not in quotes, there is no way you can read is correctly.

Comment: Yes field is not in quotes.

Comment: You have to ask the upstream application to send the field in quotes or use a different separator e.g. pipe